# Arduino and motor controlled with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class Sending : MonoBehaviour {

    //public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);

    void Start () {
        OpenConnection();
    }



    public void OpenConnection() 
    {
        if (sp != null) 
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen) 
            {
                sp.Close();
            }
            else 
            {
                sp.Open();  
            }
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit() 
    {       
        sp.Close();
    }

    public static void Contact(int pos)
    {
        string PosStr = pos.ToString ();
        Debug.Log(PosStr);
        sp.Write(PosStr);
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GetPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 dragStartPosition;
    float dragStartDistance;
    float[] Xfloat;

    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
        dragStartPosition = transform.position;
        dragStartDistance = (Camera.main.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }

    int OnMouseDrag ()
    {
        Vector3 worldDragTo = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, dragStartDistance));
        transform.position = new Vector3 (worldDragTo.x, dragStartPosition.y, dragStartPosition.z);
        new Vector3 (worldDragTo.x, dragStartPosition.y, dragStartPosition.z);
        int Newpos = (int)worldDragTo.x;
        return (Newpos);
    }

    void OnMouseUp ()
    {
        int NewPos = OnMouseDrag ();
        Sending.Contact (NewPos);
    }

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
int motorPin1 = 8;
int motorPin2 = 9;
int motorPin3 = 10;
int motorPin4 = 11;
int delayTime = 2;
int i = 0;
char myCol[5];


void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin4, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  int lf = 5;
  Serial.readBytesUntil(lf, myCol, 5);
  Serial.setTimeout(0);


  int Angle = atoi(myCol);
  int Tick = ((Angle * 51.2) / 36.0);

  Serial.println(Tick);

  if ( i < Tick)
  {
    Play();
    i++;
  }
  if (i > Tick)
  {
    Reverse();
    i--;
  }
}



void Play()
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void Reverse()
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
}
```

Hi, I have a problem with my unity controlled Motor, I have a Unity scene which contains a Cube, I can slide this cube on x axis, I send the x value through COM3, I get the Value in my Arduino and convert it to an Angle for my motor.

My problem is:
When I move the cube in Unity, my motor rotates but after I slide the cube a couple times, unity freeze like 15 / 20 sec then my motor moves but not at the right angle.

Can anyone tell me where my problem is?

Comment: I saw the-same question yesterday. I just feel like you are doing whole stuff the wrong way but will provide answer when I understand what exactly you are doing. On the Arduino side, what are expecting? You said something about motor rotating. When does it start rotating and how long does it rotate? When does it stop rotating? Do you have a real world example of what you are doing? On the Unity side, when do you send to Arduino? It looks like you are sending x value. Why are you sending x value and what is it used for? When do you stop sending to Arduino?

Comment: That's a load of questions but it will get your question answered. You can separate the Arduino and Unity response in this comment section.

Comment: I have my cube acting as a slider , i slide it on x axis and his x position is used as a angle value, i send this value in arduino.

When i drag the cube nothing happens (that's normal) when i release it the value is sent and my motor in arduino rotate (ex: i move my cube to position x 450 and my motor rotate 450°) it takes approximately 4 sec for a full rotation(360°)

the value is sent one time only on mouse release.

If i havent answer all of your question tell me please!

Comment: I understand now. What if you are in drag mode then released the mouse but you did not actually move the cube. Should the current position of the cube still be sent to Arduino? Should the cube ONLY be able to move in the  x axis during dragging or should be be allowed to move up(y-axis) too. Finally this new position you send to Arduino, is it in word or local position. By reading your code you not sending the position of the cube. I mean the x position of the cube is `gameObject.transform.position.x`

Comment: if a drag and doexnt move the cube, the value is 0 so the motor rotate 0° so it doesnt move.

The cube moves only in x axis yes.
In unity the cube position is the world position, but for my motor it just apply the angle it receives.

Comment: Here is an exemple of my problem:
I move the cub  24 on x axis --> my motor goes 24° clockwise, then i move my cube to -84 --> my motor goes like 1 or 2° counter clockwise.
Then i move the cube to 195, unity and the motor freezes does nothing then after like 20 sec the motor goes more than 720° clockwise. i can make a video if this helps.

Comment: I understand you last post. I will put my answer shortly. Was buy with something else.

Comment: i have no freezes anymore , i deleted my OpenConnection function, and add sp.Open() and sp.Close() before and after my sp.Write().

My some of my value are still making nonsense , probably in the conversion on arduino

Comment: @Programmer Oh great, i'm looking forward your answer !

Answer (score 2):

Found many mistakes in your code and I don't know which one is causing the problem. Fixed all of them. Read below to see what I fixed.

1.Unity freezing is because you are not using `Thread`.

2.Arduino freezing is very likely because you have `Serial.println(Tick);`. It sends to Unity but you did not read from the Unity side. Maybe there is a buffer overflow. Commented it out.

3.`OnMouseDrag` is a Unity callback function. Calling it by yourself from the `OnMouseUp` function is not a good idea.

4.Clicking on the side of the Cube will make it jump to the position of the mouse. Fixed it by adding an offset value.

5.Replaced `OnMouseDown`,`OnMouseDrag`, `OnMouseUp` with drag callback functions.

6.Changed the way data is read on the Arduino side. Removed `Serial.readBytesUntil(lf, myCol, 5);` code.

7.Added `delay(1);` before calling `Serial.available()`. Do not remove that. Some Arduino board require that or Serial.available() won't function as expected.

8.Removed all static stuff from your code.

9.Your string is not terminated. You must terminate it after reading with `myCol[index]= '\0';` or `myCol[index]= 0`;

I don't understand how your angle conversion is done on the Arduino side, so I left that as it was. Replace each script with the new one below and leave a comment if there is a problem. I don't have your motor so was unable to test the motor part.

**Arduino**:

```
int motorPin1 = 8;
int motorPin2 = 9;
int motorPin3 = 10;
int motorPin4 = 11;
int delayTime = 2;
char myCol[10];

enum class READSTAT {NONE, READING, DONEREADING};

READSTAT readStat = READSTAT::NONE;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin4, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  //Must delay 1 milliseconds to make Serial.available() work properly
  delay(1);

  //Serial.setTimeout(0);
  static int avalData = 0;
  if ( Serial.available() > 0) {
    readStat = READSTAT::READING;
    myCol[avalData] = Serial.read();
    avalData++;
  } else {
    //If we are in READING mode and there are no more available bytes, change mode to DONEREADING
    if (readStat == READSTAT::READING ) {
      readStat = READSTAT::DONEREADING;
      myCol[avalData] = '\0';
    }
  }

  //[CODE INSIDE HERE WILL RUN WHEN EVERY BYTE HAS BEEN RECEIVED FROM UNITY]
  //If we are in DONEREADING mode, change mode to NONE
  if (readStat == READSTAT::DONEREADING ) {

    checkMotor(avalData);

    //SET TO NONE then reset avalData
    readStat = READSTAT::NONE;
    avalData = 0;
  }

}

void checkMotor(int avalData ) {
  int Angle = atoi(myCol);
  int Tick = ((Angle * 51.2) / 36.0);


  if (0 <  Tick) {
    Tick = abs(Tick);
    for ( int i = 0; i < Tick; i++) {
      Play();
    }
  } else if (0 > Tick) {
    Tick = abs(Tick);
    for ( int i = 0; i < Tick; i++) {
      Reverse();
    }
  }
}

void Play()
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void Reverse()
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
}
```

Sending:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class Sending : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SerialPort sp;
    Thread SerialThread;
    bool stopSerialCom = true;

    bool sendNow = false;
    int posTosend = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        startCommuncation();
    }

    public void startCommuncation()
    {
        SerialThread = new Thread(onConnected);
        SerialThread.IsBackground = true;
        SerialThread.Start();
    }

    private void onConnected()
    {
        //Open Connection
        openCon();
        sp.ReadTimeout = 2;

        //Run forever until stopSerialCom = true
        while (!stopSerialCom)
        {
            //Check if we should send
            if (sendNow)
            {

                Debug.Log("Sent: " + posTosend.ToString());
                //Send
                sendToSerial(posTosend);
                posTosend = 0; //Reset to 0
                sendNow = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    private void openCon(string comPort = "COM3", int port = 9600)
    {
        sp = new SerialPort(comPort, port);

        if (sp != null)
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Close();
                sp.Open();
                stopSerialCom = false;
                Debug.Log("Opened!");
            }
            else
            {
                sp.Open();
                stopSerialCom = false;
                Debug.Log("Opened!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        stopSerialCom = true;

        //stop thread
        if (SerialThread != null && SerialThread.IsAlive)
        {
            Debug.Log("Thread Aborted!");
            SerialThread.Abort();
        }

        if (sp != null && sp.IsOpen)
        {
            sp.Close();
            Debug.Log("Closed!");
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        closeConnection();
    }


    public void Send(int pos)
    {
        posTosend = pos;
        sendNow = true;
    }

    private void sendToSerial(int pos)
    {
        try
        {
            string PosStr = pos.ToString();
            sp.Write(PosStr);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

GetPosition:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class GetPosition : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    Vector3 dragStartPosition;
    float dragStartDistance;
    float[] Xfloat;

    Vector3 clickOffset = Vector3.zero;
    Sending sending;

    Camera mainCamera;
    Transform camTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        camTransform = mainCamera.transform;
        mainCamera.gameObject.AddComponent<PhysicsRaycaster>();

        sending = GetComponent<Sending>();
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        dragStartPosition = transform.position;
        dragStartDistance = (camTransform.position - transform.position).magnitude;

        //Get offset
        clickOffset = transform.position - mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, dragStartDistance));
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, dragStartDistance));

        //Apply Offset to prevent the Cube from Jumping when mouse is clicke on the side/edge
        tempPos = tempPos + clickOffset;

        tempPos.y = dragStartPosition.y;
        tempPos.z = dragStartPosition.z;

        transform.position = tempPos;

    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        sending.Send((int)transform.position.x);
    }
}
```

Make sure that `Sending` and `GetPosition` are attached to the-same GameObject/Cube. Test with one cube only.

Comment: Just fixed something in the Arduino code. Re-copy the new Arduino code with the new one before making any comment.

Comment: It's working but not totally as expected, when i move the cube to 90 it goes  to 90° on my motor but if i move it to -10 right after, it goes 10° backward but i need it to go -10° , not 10° from the last position.